# PostreSQL ERROR: Function AVG (character varying) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, select, average

I want to calculate the average number from a column in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT AVG(col_name) 
From TableName
```

It gives me this error:

```
ERROR: function avg (character varying) does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT AVG(col_name) 
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Apparently that column is not a number but a character column. Do not store numbers in varchar (or char) columns. Change the datatype to integer, numeric or whatever suits you best.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Store numbers in a numeric field, an integer, decimal or whatever. But not in a text/varchar field.

Check the manual for all [numeric data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html).

---

Nasty workaound: CAST some records to a numeric value and keep others as text. Example:

```
/*
create temp table foo AS
SELECT x FROM (VALUES('x'),('1'),('2')) sub(x);
*/

WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN x ~ '[0-9]' THEN CAST(x AS decimal) -- cast to numeric field
    END AS num,
    CASE 
        WHEN x ~ '[a-zA-Z]' THEN x
    END AS a
FROM foo
)
SELECT AVG(num), COUNT(a) FROM cte;
```

Comment: in this column should I have numbers and letters, and for numbers I want calculate average and for leters counts